# Difference between Gunicorn and Nginx

Tags: nginx, gunicorn

This is a beginer question, but I am having trouble understanding the abstraction between Gunicorn and Nginx.  I am not looking for a detailed answer, just at a high level what is the role that each plays?  How do they interact?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per [Gunicorn's deploy doc](http://gunicorn.org/deploy.html), my understanding is that you use Nginx as a proxy server for Gunicorn.

As Gunicorn is ported from [Ruby's Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/), I'm assuming the limitations and specifications of Unicorn apply to Gunicorn as well:

> Unicorn is an HTTP server for Rack applications designed to only serve
>   fast clients on low-latency, high-bandwidth connections and take
>   advantage of features in Unix/Unix-like kernels. Slow clients should
>   only be served by placing a reverse proxy capable of fully buffering
>   both the request and response in between Unicorn and slow clients.

[Gunicorn's deploy doc](http://gunicorn.org/deploy.html) says much the same thing:

> Although there are many HTTP proxies available, we strongly advise
>   that you use Nginx. If you choose another proxy server you need to
>   make sure that it buffers slow clients when you use default Gunicorn
>   workers. Without this buffering, Gunicorn will be easily susceptible
>   to denial-of-service attacks.

So Gunicorn serves fast, low-latency high-bandwidth clients and Nginx serves the rest.

Comment: What are "slow clients" exactly ? How can we define them ?

Answer (score 9):

> Nginx is a web server and reverse-proxy responsible for serving static
>   content, gzip compression, ssl, proxy_buffers and other HTTP stuff
>   while gunicorn is a Python HTTP server that interfaces with both nginx
>   and your actual python web-app code to serve dynamic content.
>
> Here's a high-level overview of the lifecycle of an HTTP request
>   highlighting their roles. I assume that you have one server running a
>   simple app with three main processes.
>
> **Nginx**: Listens on port 80 for incoming HTTP requests from the
>   internet.
>
> **Gunicorn**: Listens on another port(8000 is the popular one) for HTTP
>   requests from Nginx. Gunicorn is configured with your python web app.